# Copy image from one folder to another folder in Unity 3d Android Platform

Tags: android, image, unity-game-engine, copy, textures

I am searching this problem for many days. I am working on Unity 3d Android Project. Is it possible to pick image on button press then copy that image to another folder on another button press? I have seen too many plugins, most of these are UnityEditor (PC Platform) and android platforms are not working. Please reply.

Comment: Why would that not be possible?

Comment: Then plz help me

Comment: Im busy helping you. You have not answered my question. Repeat: Why do think it is not possible?

Comment: I tried to implement the code from https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/FileUtil.CopyFileOrDirectory.html but thats only for PC platform. I want simple one for android platform. please help me brother

Comment: So you just want code. And you still did not answer my question.

Comment: I have a code which copies an image from "Test1" folder to "Test2" folder in the internal storage directory. For that purpose i have to put image in "Test1" folder every time. Now I want a button which opens the file explorer / file browser and when I press the button, i could select image in any folder then it saves to my target folder "Test2"

Comment: Then what is the problem? Only the source path will be different then. Please show the source path you have now and an example of a source path the user choosed.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code

```
    using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;

    public class FileC : MonoBehaviour
    {
    public void save()
        {
            string fileName = "a.png";

        string sourcePath = @"/mnt/sdcard/Test1";

        string targetPath =  @"/mnt/sdcard/Test2";


            // Use Path class to manipulate file and directory paths.
            string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
            string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

            // To copy a folder's contents to a new location:
            // Create a new target folder, if necessary.
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
            }

        // Create a new target folder, if necessary.
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(sourcePath);
        }

            // To copy a file to another location and 
            // overwrite the destination file if it already exists.
            System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);

            // To copy all the files in one directory to another directory.
            // Get the files in the source folder. (To recursively iterate through
            // all subfolders under the current directory, see
            // "How to: Iterate Through a Directory Tree.")
            // Note: Check for target path was performed previously
            //       in this code example.
            if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
            {
                string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);

                // Copy the files and overwrite destination files if they already exist.
                foreach (string s in files)
                {
                    // Use static Path methods to extract only the file name from the path.
                    fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
                    destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
                    System.IO.File.Copy(s, destFile, true);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Source path does not exist!");
            }

            // Keep console window open in debug mode.
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        }


    }
```

Comment: Please dont put your code as answer but in your post.